# Is it possible to derive the work-energy theorem using only $F=ma$ and the geometry of newtonian space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

Is it possible to derive the work-energy theorem using only $F=ma$ and the geometry of newtonian space?

That is, is it possible to derive the work-energy theorem without any prior definition: just $F=ma$ and the geometry of newtonian space.

Comment: how can you derive the work-energy theorem without defining what work and kinetic energy? Kinetic energy is literally defined as the work done in accelerating an object from rest to its current velocity, and work is defined as the dot product of force and displacement. Energy and work have strict mathematical definitions.

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH In an axiomatic system once the axioms are declared all theorems follow logically. This process of arriving at theorems leads to concepts that you may well want to give a name to. Example, in geometry there are classes of theorems that give rise to the concept of area. You can choose to define a particular concept as 'area'. Whether or not that definition is in place, the theorems follow anyway. Manipulation of symbols can produce a result (formal theorem) that suggests new concepts to name.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate Newton's second law with respect to distance along a path

$$ \int  \mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf s = m \int  \mathbf a\cdot d\mathbf s $$

We have $$\frac{d\dot x^2}{dx} = \frac{d\dot x^2}{d\dot x} \frac{d\dot x}{d t}\frac{dt}{d x} = 2 \dot x \ddot x\frac{1}{\dot x} = 2 \ddot x $$

Then, in Cartesian coordinates (for convenience) we may write the integral as the sum of three terms
$$ m \big( \int   \ddot x  dx + \int   \ddot y  dy +\int   \ddot z  dz \big ) = \frac m 2 \big( \int  \frac{d\dot x^2}{dx} dx + \int  \frac{d\dot y^2}{dy} dy +\int  \frac{d\dot z^2}{dz} dz \big)$$

from which the result follows immediately, prompting the definition of work:

$$ W = \int  \mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf s $$

Comment: This answer fails to meet the the criterium stated in the question: the question calls specifically for a derivation without any prior definition.

Comment: @Cleonis: Without prior definition of what? Work? You can't prove statements about things which you haven't defined.

Comment: Obviously if work is not defined, the work energy theorem cannot even be stated, let alone proved. You must also remove the word "work" from your own answer, since you do not allow it to be defined. The theorem is simply the integration of Newton's second law with respect to distance. We define the word work because the theorem holds, not the other way about.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos In an axiomatic system once the axioms are declared all theorems follow logically. This process of arriving at theorems leads to concepts that you may well want to give a name to. Example, in geometry there are classes of theorems that give rise to the concept of area. You can choose to define a particular concept as 'area'. Whether or not that definition is in place, the theorems follow anyway. Manipulation of symbols can produce a result (formal theorem) that suggests new concepts to name.

Comment: Then you should recognise that even its original form, the answer met your criterion, since nothing in the derivation depends on the word "work".

Comment: @CharlesFrancis So let's summerize. We recognize that one way or another an integration must be performed. The strategy of your proof is to start with setting up the integral of force over distance. There is the judgement call whether to treat the case of uniform acceleration, or to accommodate the more general acceleration-a-function-of-position. For the purpose of the question I opted to present the minimal derivation, one for the case of uniform acceleration. Anyway, the purpose is to hammer home that the entire physics input into the work-energy theorem is F=ma. The rest is mathematics.

Comment: It is not a judgement call not to use uniform acceleration. The theorem is general. Why should you seek to hammer home something which is already clear and well known? And why make it obscure with a round the houses argument, when there is a well known standard derivation?

Answer (score 0):

Newton's law of motion states that

$$
\mathbf F = m \mathbf a
$$
What happens if we define the scalar quantity "Work" as force applied along a path product the path as
$$
\mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf s  = m \mathbf a \cdot d\mathbf s
$$
re-writing
$$
\mathbf a= \frac{d \mathbf v}{dt}
$$
Equation becomes
$$
\mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf s  = m \frac{d \mathbf v}{dt} \cdot d\mathbf s
$$
where it becomes
$$
\mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf s  = m \mathbf v \cdot {d \mathbf v} 
$$
where the right hand side is infinite small form of something which in case called "energy" and left hand called "Work"
$$
dW  = dT
$$
if you integrate them over a curve to find the well known expression of the equation
$$
\int dW  = \int m \mathbf v \cdot {d \mathbf v} 
$$
then
$$
\int dW  = m(\int  \dot x d \dot x+ \int  \dot y d \dot y+\int  \dot z d \dot z)
$$
finally
$$
W  = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot x^2 +\dot y^2+\dot z^2)
$$
can be derived which is an expanded form of the well know equation
$$
W = \frac{1}{2}m (\mathbf v \cdot  \mathbf v)
$$

Comment: This question was intended as a self-answer question. (Stackexchange supports and encourages self-answer format) In the derivation I present F=ma is brought in at the very end. The purpose of that is to emphasize that to go from F=ma to the work-energy theorem is truly a single step. (It appears many people are unaware of this.) It would be interesting to set up the integration relation in complete form first, and at the very last step show that combining with F=ma produces the work-energy theorem in a single step. That way it is clear what part is mathematics, and what part is physics

Comment: The generalization to a space with three spatial dimensions is useful of course, but for the purpose of the question not necessary. By contrast: if generalizing to three spatial dimensions would be hard then to present a derivation for one spatial dimenstion only would be an oversimplification. In this case the generalization to three spatial dimensions is trivial. In my opinion the generalization to three spatial dimensions is not a bare essential.

Comment: What about total energy?Question states newtonian geometry. If you can look closely you will see that the energy depends to motion on all coordinates. This form is essential for expression of the Energy because without three dimensional derivation you can not tell anyone that the Energy is sum of the energy parts of all the dimensions. Also spatial derivation here is essential.

Comment: Among the implications of using newtonian geometry is that we have Pythagoras' theorem as a given. Hence for three velocity components have the following for the total energy $\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 = \tfrac{1}{2}m{v_x}^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}m{v_y}^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}m{v_z}^2 $ that is: the generalization from 1-dimensional to 3-dimensional is *automatic*. The generalization is already there because the expression for kinetic energy is quadratic to begin with.

Comment: I think you are stuck here and completely wrong. Your Pythagoras' theorem applies to velocity only  as here because it is a vector but Energy not. Here you pre assume that Energy is equal to $\frac{1}{2}m v^2$ before defining energy. I won't answer you anymore since you are some kind of ROTE.

Answer (score -1):

In order to present the derivation I need to get something out of the way first:

The newtonian view of space and time is expressed in the first law:
"An object not subject to any force will proceed such that in equal intervals of time it covers equal intervals of distance."
The first law is a statement about motion, asserting that uniformity of space and uniformity of time are a single uniformity. We need to expand the concept of 'geometry' to accommodate that unity. In that sense Newton's first law is a geometric statement, and not a statement of dynamics, even though it is an assertion about motion.

The kinematic relations used in this derivation should be thought of as expressing the newtonian concept of space and time.

The following two standard kinematic relations are valid for the case of uniform acceleration. The derivation will capitalize on these relations:

Change of velocity as a function of time:

$$ v = v_0 + at  \qquad (1)  $$

Change of position as a function of time:

$$ s = s_0 + v_0t + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2    \qquad (2) $$

These aren't statements of dynamics. In effect they are geometrical statements. When space and time are newtonian then (1) and (2) are valid.

(1) and (2) are of course closely related: when you differentiate (2) you get (1). As we know, diffentiation and integration are essentially inverse operations of each other.

(1) can be restated in the form of (3), and then you substitute the $t$ in (2) with the expression for $t$ from (3)

$$ t = (v - v_0)/a   \qquad (3)  $$

After the substitution:

$$ s = s_0 + v_0\frac{(v-v_0)}{a} + \tfrac{1}{2} a \frac{{(v-v_0)}^2}{a^2}  \qquad (4)  $$

Moving position and acceleration to the left so that on the right only velocity terms remain:

$$ a(s-s_0) = vv_0 - {v_0}^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - vv_0 + \tfrac{1}{2} {v_0}^2  \qquad (5)  $$

On the right side several terms drop away against each other.
The resulting relation:

$$ a(s - s_0) = \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}v_0^2    \qquad  (6)  $$

The above expression is also known as [Torricelli's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_equation)
As mentioned above, through (2) this expression is in effect a result of integration.

(6) is still not in the realm of dynamics. The content of (6) is the same as the content of (1) and (2): valid if space and time are newtonian.

By combining (6) and F=ma we obtain a *dynamics* statement.

$$ F \Delta s = \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}mv_0^2   \qquad (7) $$

Discussion:
Is it possible for someone who has not yet been introduced to the concept of work to arrive at (7), just by sheer manipulation of symbols?

I take it as obvious that the answer to that is *yes*.

Of course, that person-who-has-not-yet-been-introduced-to-the-concept-of-work will not have the name 'work-energy theorem' at his disposal. To that person it will be an as yet unnamed theorem.

But clearly (7) is highly suggestive.
Once you have (7) formulating the concept of work is a no-brainer.

(Of course, to a person who has no expectation that a concept of work will be useful there is no incentive to do the manipulations that arrive at (7). Presumably that is why the work-energy theorem was recognized relatively late in the history of physics, around 1820-1830)

**General remarks**

Many people are under the false impression that the concept of [Work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)) is an independent concept, a concept that one can choose to define, if one finds it practical to do so.

The purpose of this derivation is to demonstrate that 'work done' and 'kinetic energy' are literally just a single step away from F=ma

(A more general derivation is for the case where acceleration is a function of the position coordinate. That generalization is straightforward.)

LATER EDIT (4 days later):
Torricelli's formula is really an integration, but the integration is implicit. It should be explicit.

The steps in the following derivation are all towards the end goal of obtaining an expression in terms of the velocity $v$

In the course of the derivation the following two relations will be used:

$$ ds = v \ dt  \qquad (11)  $$

$$ dv = \frac{dv}{dt}dt  \qquad (12)   $$

The integral for acceleration from a starting point $s_0$ to a final point $s$

$$ \int_{s_0}^s a \ ds \qquad (13)  $$

Use (11) to change the differential from *ds* to *dt*. Since the differential is changed the limits change accordingly.

$$ \int_{t_0}^t a \ v \ dt \qquad (14) $$

Rearrange the order, and write the acceleration $a$ as $\tfrac{dv}{dt}$

$$ \int_{t_0}^t v \ \frac{dv}{dt} \ dt  \qquad (15) $$

Use (12) for a second change of differential, again the limits change accordingly.

$$ \int_{v_0}^v v \ dv  \qquad (16)  $$

Putting everything together:

$$ \int_{s_0}^s a \ ds = \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}v_0^2  \qquad (17) $$

(17) is the counterpart of Torricelli's formula (6).

Comment: "These aren't statements of dynamics. In effect they are geometrical statement" .. what is difference between a statement of dynamics and a statement of geometry?

Comment: I think I get what you are saying that there is a point of time for each point in space but I don't get how exactly you're calling this a geometry

Comment: Damn yeah , it's a phenomena we can experience without the numbers. Is that correct? The coordinate is just a way of describing something deeper

Comment: can you elaborate more on how you arrived at (4) from the previous equations, perhaps by breaking down the steps involved?

Comment: Assuming the acceleration is constant makes this derivation a specialized case, which is not what you asked for.

Comment: @BillN Torricelli's formula is in terms of $\Delta s$ which can be taken to the limit of infinitisimally small increments. Anyway, the work-energy theorem states an integration property; it's worthwhile to present a derivation that makes that integration explicit, so I added that